# Regarding Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR) for non-linear problems

Tags: spatial-statistics, statistics, gis-principle, geographically-weighted-regression

I am new to this topic.
I am referring to this [Geographically Weighted Regression](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/geographically-weighted-regression) tutorial. From my understanding, GWR does a weighted regression to model the dependencies between exploratory and dependent variables.

Most of the tutorials I found online use GWR to find the weights assigned to variables of a linear system. I was wondering if GWR can be used to model non-linear systems. For example, in [this](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/geographically-weighted-regression) link they mention GWR can be used for climate applications. But climate is a highly chaotic dynamical system which is heavily non-linear.

How can GWR be used for this purposed if at its heart GWR is a linear model?

Comment: What is making you think that GWR is an appropriate model for your application? If you are modeling climate process it is unlikely that your data is nonstationary (unless you have data on true microclimate variation). GWR is really only appropriate when 2nd order autocorrelation comes into play, otherwise one should be looking at other modeling methods. Locally, climate would be quite linear and homogeneous. Nonliner relationships would not be observable until modeled at larger spatial extents. This alone negates a "nonlinear" GWR approach.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Thanks a lot for your response. I am mostly working with sea level rise elevation data (basically modelling the sea level along a coastal region using data from other parts of the US). Do you think GWR would have inherent shortcomings in this use case? Can you please direct me to other methods if you think are better suited for the use case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Methodologically that could be anything from a simple linear model to something like a gradient boosting approach. It depends on what your intent is and how you are planning on drawing inference, if at all. But, yes GWR has huge shortcoming having nothing to do with  your proposed use. It cannot account for first order effects so, unless you are trying to perform exploratory analysis on nonstationary data, it has no valid role in formal statistical modeling. Generally, even given appropriate use, it results in a locally over-dispersed estimate with huge bias because the global trend is absent.